# Listview widget isn't working in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to Android Studio.For me there is a problem with listview. I've set all the ids properly and yet the problem occurs.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.prashanthwagle.myapplication.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.example.prashanthwagle.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] s={"asfasaf","bafaf","cbfbd"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sample);


    ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,R.layout.activity_main,s);

    listView.setAdapter(a);

}
}
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys, this was a very silly question. Anyways thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please accept the answers that helped to get to your solution. :) :)

Comment: @user8114776: are you familiar with accepting answers? To do that, decide which answer you prefer, and click the tick mark to its left, so that it turns green. It is not mandatory to do so, but it is considered helpful for others, and as an expression of gratitude.

Comment: Downvoted (for not replying, see above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think that you should change

```
ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,R.layout.activity_main,s)
```

;
to

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R. android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the wrong layout for ArrayAdapter. Use this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
```

The layout reference in the adapter initialization and assignment should not be the layout reference of your activity. Basically, this parameter tells the ListView what type of layout will each row of the list have. Read more about this from here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html